# Book recommendation for Green's functions

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, greens-function

I'm want to understand Green's functions, but not just the definition. In particular, consider the equation $-ΔG_j(x)=δ(x-x_j)$ for $x\in Ω\subset\mathbb{C}$ with boundary condition $G_j(x)=0$ for $x\in\partial Ω$ for some fixed point $x_j$.

I know the limit of $G_j$ while $x_j\to\infty$ should exist (possibly under some additional assumptions) and this is what we call Green's function of $\partial Ω$ with a pole at infinity. (Please, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Can anybody elaborate over this or suggest a good book/paper for reference?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the elementary definition? So you're saying you want a book that explains the concept of "Green's function of $\partial \Omega$ with a pole at infinity"?

Comment: @littleO: Yes, that's correct!
By "elementary definition" I meant to say that I don't want a book which is (only) introductory. Maybe I'll edit that out.